# Eisenstein integers multiplication closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to show that the Eisenstein integers $$R = \{ m + nw \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\ w = e^{i \frac{2\pi}{3}}$$
are closed under multiplication.

By using $e^{i \frac{2\pi}{3}} = -\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ I get
$$ ( m_1 + n_1w)(m_2 + n_2w)\\ = \left(m_1 m_2 + \frac{m_1n_2}{2} + \frac{m_2 n_1}{2} + \frac{n_1 n_1}{2} -\frac{3}{4} \right) + i \left( m_1 + m_2 - \frac{n_1}{2} -\frac{n_2}{2} \right) \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$

I am confused because the brackets don't seem to be integers for all values of $m_1, m_2, n_1, n_2$.

Comment: Use $w^2+w+1=0$.

Comment: Nice, thanks! (15 chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=a+b\omega$ and $b=c+d\omega$ be two elements of $R$, with $\omega$ a primitive third root of unity, i.e., equal to $w$. Note that $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$, as the sum of $n$-th roots of unity is zero. We obtain
$$
(a+b\omega)(c+d\omega)=ac+(ad+bc)\omega+bd\omega^2.
$$
Now replace $\omega^2$ by $-1-\omega$ and you are done, ie., $xy\in R$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "sum of n-th roots" part? If I use cosinus, I see that the identity is true in the current case but your more general statement sounds interesting.

Comment: For every primitive $n$-th root of unity $\zeta$ we have $1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\cdots +\zeta^{n-1}=0$. Just make a picture on the unit circle. For $n=3$ we have $1+\zeta+\zeta^2=0$.

Comment: I am still a bit confused about what you write. What am I supposed to draw in the circle?

Comment: Draw all complex numbers $1,e^{2\pi i/n},\ldots ,e^{(n-1)2\pi i/n}$ and add them as vectors in the plane. Then it is obvious that the result is zero.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that the Eisenstein integers are the numbers of the form $\frac{a+bi\sqrt{3}}{2}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers of the same parity.